# Can I change the colours gulp serve uses?

Tags: spfx-tooling

I am having difficulty reading the deep red, purple and green and deep blue that gulp serve uses in the node.js console.  Can I change these colours ?

I have tried using the properties of the `node.js` console but that does not seem to affect the colours only the background.

Comment: The version of gulp was obtained using the SharePoint SPFx tutorial instructions so I assumed was part pf spfx-tooling.

Answer (score 0):

The gulp tasks are defined by the tooling and you cannot customize them.

But as a fellow half color blind dude I agree that a `nocolor` mode would be good.

Comment: You could manually go and edit the colors in the /node_modules/gulp-core-build-serve/lib/serveTask.js.  But you would need to do that each time  the module was updated.